# Remote MySQL access with encryption

Tags: mysql, encryption

Now I have a role as QA / tester in my workplace. We have a desktop application (will be installed in end-user pc) which requires to submit a voucher ID to a remote server. During the submission I realized through Wireshark that the MySQL packets are not encrypted. I can see both username-password in plain text and also the voucher id which are being sent.

If I want to encrypt the MySQL communication, what are the ways to do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL supports connecting over SSL.  Read the [Using SSL for Secure Connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/secure-connections.html) section of the manual.